# Ionic 7 How do I change the space between checkbox and label for an ion-checkbox?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic7

How do I change the space / margin / padding between the checkbox itself and the text label next to it in a ion-checkbox in Ionic7?

`<ion-checkbox labelPlacement="end">Visa ålder</ion-checkbox>`

There seems to be a shadow part label but I cannot change it.

Comment: The docs state how to edit styles....... https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/checkbox#css-shadow-parts

Comment: @StackoverBlows I have read the documentation, I think you need to be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to set margin-inline-start for the shadow part label. Put this in your scss file:

```
ion-checkbox {

   &::part(label)
   {
      margin-inline-start: 5px;
   }
}
```